# JqGrid next button enabled for no values are returned

Tags: jqgrid

We have an issue when no values are returned from Jqgrid. In this case next button of pager (jqGrid) is enabled. We have to disable it when grid is empty. Please help me in finding a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the next button as disabled you can do the following:

```
$('#next_' + yourgridid + '_pager').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

To re-enable the button do:

```
$('#next_' + yourgridid + '_pager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

I suggest doing this in the [loadComplete(data)](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents&s%5B%5D=loadcomplete) event.

```
$("#yourgridid").jqGrid({
...
   loadComplete: function(data){ 
       var records = $('#yourgridid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
       //note: you can also get record count via data.records or data.rows.length in this function
       if (records > 0) {
            $('#next_' + yourgridid + '_pager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
       } else {
            $('#next_' + yourgridid + '_pager').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
       }
   },
...
});
```

Comment: damn me, i was thinking he's talking about a button some where in his page. he didn't mention about next button of pager. your code will work great in his case.

Comment: Great solution, worked perfectly for me, Your description was awesome

Answer (score 0):

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
                  var page = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
                  var lastpage = $("#mygrid").getGridParam('lastpage');
                 //note: you can also get record count via data.records or data.rows.length in this function
                if (lastpage > page) {
                     $('#next_mygridpager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                     $('#last_mygridpager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                 } else {
                     $('#next_mygridpager').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                     $('#last_mygridpager').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                 }
            }
```

I believe this is a more complete solution because you also do not want the next and last button appear when there are no more pages to move forward.